# Retrieve documents based on an element inside an array in each document

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am working on an elastic query which need to return all the documents based on an attribute which is inside the first element in an array in the document. Please refer the document structure below.

**User document**

```json
{
  "name": "Sam",
  "age": 20,
  "vehicle": [
    {
      "type": "car",
      "capacity": 4,
      "registration": {
        "date": "20.02.2020",
        "plate": null
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

> Every document only having 1 element in vehicle array.

Above is a sample document in my ES and the requirement is to get all the documents which has "null" value for **plate** attribute (similar to the example) in collection. I have tried various queries for two days but non of them got succeeded and got errors in query. What's the solution to this?

Comment: What is type vehicle Field? Provide a document with null field vehicle

Comment: @rabbitbr I am extremely sorry that I have made a mistake in asking the question. I need the document that has null value for plate field in that doc. Please help me in that.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is check any field exists inside field "vehicle" for example: field "type".

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "vehicle",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": [
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "vehicle.registration.plate"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am extremely sorry that I have made a mistake in asking the question. I need the document that has null value for plate field in that doc. Please help me in that.